# Inheritance means inheriting the accessible method or inheriting all members but some can't be accessible in subclass?

Tags: java, inheritance

I used to consider inheritance as inheriting all members but some can't be accessible in subclass.  But I found a book says that subclass can inherit all the methods it can access.

I think a subclass should has all of its superclass's abilities.  If it doesn't have superclass's private abilities, how can the inherited accessible abilities based on private abilities work?

Did I get into a dead end? What's the common view of Inheritance?

Answer (score 1):

You can say that the sub-class inherits the private methods of its parent class indirectly. While it can't call them directly, it can call non-private methods of the parent class that call the private methods.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement:

```
I used to consider inheritance as inheriting all members but some can't be accessable in subclass.But I found a book says that subclass can inherit all the methods it can access.
```

Lets parse this statement of yours:

---

> **1.** I used to consider inheritance as inheriting all members but some
>   can't be accessable in subclass.

**Extract:** When you inherit from a super class then all its members are available in the sub class however the private members of the super class are not accesible from with in the sub class.

---

> **2.** But I found a book says that subclass can inherit all the methods it
>   can access.

**Extract:** Yes the book is saying it perfectly,All the methods it can access(the non private methods you are left with are annotated as the ones to be accessible in that book of yours),that is other than the **private ones.**

---

I was thinking to link a very good question asked some where on SO,but i am not able to search it,but I had saved the image in that answer on my computer; to make you more clear about inheritance,i am going to upload it,the image was something like this [image]